# Generic Delegate Storage and Usage

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

```
delegate IEnumerable<T> GetFromSQLDelegate<T>(...);
public GetFromSQLDelegate myFunctionToCall;
```

The above does not compile because myFunctionToCall does not specify a type. I'm trying to "store" a generic delegate such that I can invoke it later as a regular generic function:

```
// ... somewhere in another code base ...
return MyObject.myFunctionToCall<string>(...);
```

C# complains because I'm not specifying a concrete type on the delegate storage property. Is there a (good) way to "store" a delegate capable of invoking a generic function without implementing various concrete type delegate scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the value as `System.Delegate`, make it `private`, and define a function `GetDelegate<T>` that casts your stored delegate to the appropriate type:

```
private Delegate storedDelegate;

public myFunctionToCall<T> GetDelegate<T>() {
    return (myFunctionToCall<T>)storedDelegate;
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
return MyObject.GetDelegate<string>()(...);
```

There is a little bit of ugliness going on around the `()(...)` syntax, but it should probably do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect cast to work if T does not match type used for function that was originally assigned to the delegate. Or I'm missing a way how to actually assign the value to the delegate?

Comment: By making the delegate private (as explicitly called for by dasblinkenlight) you are implying a contract by which only the sender can "set" the delegate, and all the consumers are able to get (but not set) the delegate because the sender informs the consumer of a signature that works. This pattern fails only if the sender fails to match the delegate with accompanying functions that call the delegate.

Comment: Your solution is not perfect (because it involves boxing/unboxing) but it appears as close as one can get without compromising on a design. Thank you. :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Martin is correct, this is going to work only under the assumption that the caller sets and then gets the delegate with the matching type.

Comment: +1 For knowing what the question mean. I personally would try not drop compile time safety... but whatever works for particular scenario and produce cleaner code is good.

Comment: @MartinBliss I think you meant downcasting, not boxing, and it is indeed not perfect. We have been using a similar pattern in one of our core libraries at work, and it serves us just fine :)

Comment: If you are setting the delegate in 1 place and using it in another, why can't you specify the generic on the field? In my opinion the thing that "sets" the field should have been included in the original question.

Comment: @rally25rs I cannot specify generic class on the field because the class that hosts the field is not generic: rather, it is a regular class with two generic functions (one setter and one getter).

Comment: dasblinkenlight: Isn't downcasting just a special form of boxing/unboxing? If every delegate is ultimately of base type Delegate, is casting back and forth from that base class no different than casting any object to Object and back? Is there not a chance for unintended narrow/widening conversion if the programmer fails to match the "real" type of an object at the end?

Comment: @MartinBliss My understanding is that [Microsoft uses terms *boxing* and *unboxing*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) specifically to describe making objects out of value types (i.e. `struct`s, `int`s, `double`s, and so on). You are 100% correct on everything else.

Answer (score 0):

There are no pieces to your puzzle in C#:

- you can't have non-generic variable of generic type with non-specified type
- you can't create function that matches such imaginary signature
- you can't call function and specify type.

So answer is NO. There are multiple different ways to achieve similar behaviors, so if you specify what your actual goal is someone will come up with an approach.

Comment: As the question implies, I'm trying to store a function's reference to an object which is then passed around to other objects (of which don't know about the sending object) to invoke the function at hand. The only thing the objects have in common is a contract regarding the function signature.  I don't see why this feature doesn't or couldn't exist as this shouldn't break type safety. The core requirement is that the sender must specify a function without exposing itself (public or private) to consumers of the delegate.

Comment: You want to "strip" type of generic function, which is not possible to my knowledge as generic type is part of function's signature... Still trying to digest what you want.

Comment: Looks like you are happy with @dasblinkenlight solution - so keeping this answer solely as it have useful comment about requirements.

Comment: Class A has functions that many other classes (Class B, C, and D for example) need access to. Class A has public functions (unrelated to the delegate) that are designed to be called in a sequence, thus I don't want to expose Class A to other classes unfamiliar with the sequence, allowing for confusion or worse. The alternative is to pass an object from Class A to other classes containing delegates so as to avoid exposing Class A directly to mischief.

Comment: People who praise "single responsibility principle" may not survive reading the sentence :). Consider if you can split classes in such a way you can use proper typed delegate. But as I've said - your code may be better of with this approach.

Comment: Alexei: I've decided to abandon my design (and along with it, this solution) because I could not come up with a good reason why I couldn't simply provide the functions in the object being passed around versus the producer. So, in a way, you are correct that a re-design is probably more appropriate than applying this solution.